# Adding CSV upload browse button to Ext.Action

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, csv, ext-js

I am trying to create a CSV File upload on GeoExt Map App.
I need to place the upload function within the Ext.Action, so that I can add it to the toolbar of the GeoExt Panel. I am trying to implement this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File). Here is my code,

```
action = new Ext.Action({
        text: "Upload Excel",
        control: new Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                title: 'Upload a CSV File',
                width: 400,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                frame: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    name: 'csv',
                    fieldLabel: 'CSV Upload',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    buttonText: 'Select CSV File'
                }],

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Upload',
                    handler : function() {
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                        if(form.isValid()){
                            form.submit({
                                url: 'file-upload.py',
                                waitMsg: 'Uploading the CSV File...',
                                success: function(fp, o) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your csv file "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                                }   
                            }); 
                        }   
                    }
                }]
        }), 
        map: map,
        // button options
        tooltip: "Upload CSV File",
        // check item options
        group: "newTool"
    });
    actions["upCSV"] = action;
    toolbarItems.push(action);
```

Firebug keeps giving me this error,

`TypeError: b[d.xtype || e] is not a constructor`

Am I declaring the function incorrectly within the Ext.Action?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is such a pain in the ass to debug!

I can't find the problem in your code but here are some points that will help you to find it:

- Get the non minified version of Ext.
- Put some "console.log('>> function x start')" , "console.log('<< function x end')"  in your code.
- As a final resource place "debbuger;" at the start.

Since it's a generic ExtJS question, you can also ask it at Stackoverflow.